# an error of huawei map sometimes initiating and sometimes not?

Tags: android, maps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

this is the error:

E/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_130: getRemoteContext:  DynamicModule load  failedcom.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule$LoadingException: Query  huawei_module_maps unavailable, errorCode:4

Answer (score 0):

4(MODULE_NOT_READY): The framework is not initialized.

This error code is added after HMS 3.0 is switched to HMS 4.0.

This error code indicates that the current framework is being initialized (for example, the PMS is not initialized, the module copy is not complete, or the SO decompression is not complete). The module information query result can be obtained only after the initialization is complete.

Therefore, you are advised to perform a wait operation and then try again when the service receives the error code. Generally, the initialization takes a long time only when the framework is initialized for the first time.